# How to efficiently update a copy of a large binary file

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, file-transfer, binary-files

I have a large file (~20 GB, VirtualBox VM of Windows XP) that I would like to clone to a second computer and then keep synchronized, 1-way, from the primary computer.

Is there a generic way of updating only the changed parts of a binary file?

If there is not a generic tool, is there a specific way to do this for VirtualBox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about, well, `rsync`?  It uses a block delta transfer algorithm by default.

Comment: You are right. I didn't know rsync worked with binary files.

Answer (score 4):

I just used [xdelta](http://code.google.com/p/xdelta/downloads/list)

This creates a diff file that others can download from a server to apply locally. More fiddly than rsync, but you can use this method without having to give your box users access to rsync your server.

Simple install on my mint (debian) computer and worked very nicely:

```
sudo apt-get install xdelta
```

then to get the details

```
man xdelta
```

To make the diff, very easy:

```
xdelta delta b4.2.box b5.0.box b4.2.to.5.0.patch
```

apparently uses the rsync algorithm